# How to get selected word from WebView using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, webview

I am loading local pdf file in such way

```
let myProjectBundle: NSBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
let filePath: String = myProjectBundle.pathForResource("test2", ofType: "pdf")!
let myURL = NSURL(string: filePath)
let myURLRequest: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: myURL!)
self.webView.loadRequest(myURLRequest)
```

How can I get selected word ? This one returns empty string every time

```
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("window.getSelection().toString();")
```

does not work with pdf file.

Many thanks!

Comment: hello..!! Any idea u got it? I too trying the same. That function working only on HTML. not in PDF. If u know how to do that, kindly guide me. pls..